# RetrieveAPIView Django Rest framework, return custom response when lookup_field detail does not exists in database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django rest framework.
I have a model and serializer. Trying to retrieve data using RetrieveAPIView using a lookup_field.

I want to return custom response when lookup_filed data does not exits in database.

Below is my view

```
class GetData(RetrieveAPIView):    
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    lookup_field='id'
    action = "retrieve"
    def get_queryset(self):           
       Data.objects.all()
```

This is my response:
{
"detail": "Not found."
}

Comment: If you override `def get_queryset()`, please `return` the queryset, your code above does not return queryset, but return `None`.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the object exists in the database, with the id you are querying on you should be able to retrieve the object using `RetrieveAPIView` as such:

in your `views.py` file:

```
class GetData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

in your `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('your_custom_path/<pk>', GetData.as_view())
]
```

This will return the object with the specified primary key (id) as defined in the path you run the request against.

GET /your_custom_path/2 will return the Data object with an id of 2. This super simple code is the benefit of using the `RetrieveAPIView` if you want to add more customizable filtering I would request looking into `APIView` on the official django rest framework docs